# Moq a function call to a different class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Hi I need to mock the following method using Moq.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TagsViewModel tagsViewModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { sid = specification.SpecificationId }).Success("Saved Successfully!");
}
```

But I received an exception in the above line. The problem is, with in the Success() method there, it utilizes 'System.Web.HttpContext' class without mocking which the code fails. So I thought about mocking the 'Success' method itself, within the test method, so that I don't have to worry about mocking HttpContext. Is that possible? (The 'Success()' method is in a different class than the test class)

Comment: Can you please show how the test method looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TagsViewModel tagsViewModel)
{
    var someUnknownObj = TestableRedirectToAction(tagsViewModel);
    return someUnknownObj.Success("Saved Succesfully");        
}

internal someUnknownObjType TestableRedirectToAction(TagsViewModel tagsViewModel)
{
    // ................................
    // ................................
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { sid = specification.SpecificationId })
}
```

Now test the TestableRedirectToAction method which carries all your logic - Success()